# D'où vient l'expression "belle lurette" ?

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques

J'ai lu l'autre jour "maison fondée il y a belle lurette" sur un panneau publicitaire et je me demande d'où vient cette expression. Est-ce que "lurette" est employé ailleurs dans la langue ?

Comment: Tout ce que vous voulez savoir se trouve à l'entrée « lurette » du TLFi.

Answer (score 1):

Ce mot, d'après le TLFi, est familier et employé presque uniquement avec l'adj. belle; il est synonyme de « longtemps ».

On trouve le mot dans des locutions avec les présentatifs « *il y a* », « *depuis* » et « *voici* » (TLFi).

- Il y a (belle) lurette (que). Il y a (bien) longtemps (que).

Encore à partir du TLFi on peut apprendre que le mot est « Formé par corruption de heurette dans l'expr. il y a belle heurette. Heurette, dimin. de heure* attesté en a. fr. (1119, hurete PHILIPPE DE THAON, Comput, 2069, cf. T.-L.), est resté vivant dans différentes régions, notamment dans le Nord et dans l'Est ».

La [précision suivante](http://www.linternaute.fr/expression/langue-francaise/211/il-y-a-belle-lurette/) est intéressante;

« Cette expression est apparue en 1877. En fait, le mot lurette n'existe pas, il s'agit d'un mix entre belle et heurette signifiant une petite heure. Le mot belle amplifie largement cette durée indiquant ainsi un temps d'attente plus long. »

On apprend au [Wiktionaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/belle_lurette) que

« belle lurette » est une « locution créée par **métanalyse** de la locution « il y a belle heurette » (heurette étant un diminutif d’heure) [et que] l’association entre l’adjectif « belle » et un diminutif de temps donne, comme dans « un bon bout de temps », un sens de grande durée ».